# Footer-switch-currency in Magento 2 don't show select

Tags: magento2, currency

I have a codazon Unlimited theme , but when i add the selector in footer this don't work.
I tried to talk with the support but no answers.

```
{{block name="footer-top" class="Magento\Framework\View\Element\Template" template="Magento_Theme::html/footer-top.phtml" child_blocks="footer-switch-language,footer-switch-currency"}}
```

[image]

[image]

but on the front page i have this.

[image]

Please help me guys, I need to deliver it.

Thanks